# Musicg fingerprint for audio input

Tags: android, audio-fingerprinting

In musicg I can compare fingerprints of  Wave files by the following code :

```
double score =
new FingerprintsSimilarity(
    new Wave("voice1.wav").getFingerprint(),
    new Wave("voice2.wav").getFingerprint() ).getSimilarity();
```

Instead of saving audio and comparing, can I directly feed MIC input to get the fingerprints similarity ?

Eg :

```
double score =
new FingerprintsSimilarity(
    AudioFromMIC(),
    new Wave("voice2.wav").getFingerprint() ).getSimilarity();
```

Edit :
In the Wave.java  , function initWaveWithInputStream() can I send feed MIC input as Inputstream ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Hi, Have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: No.Not yet. Anything from your side ?

Answer (score 0):

The Wave() method accepts only the InpustStream type as parameter. Please refer to the code below:

```
InputStream in1 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sound1);
InputStream in2 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sound2);

Wave wave1 = new Wave(in1);
Wave wave2 = new Wave(in2);
FingerprintSimilarity fingerprintSimilarity = wave1.getFingerprintSimilarity(wave2);
```